# find -exec grep in series with an inverted grep, find nested grep

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, grep

I have the following three files

```
**file_01.sh**  
GOOD_word  
bla bla BAD_word  
miao GOOD_word bau  
BAD_word
GOOD_word foo
```

```
**file_02.sh**  
GOOD_word yes  
GOOD_word bla bla BAD_word  
GOOD_word bla  
BAD_word
```

```
**file_03.sh**  
just BAD_word  
and bla bla
```

I would like to have the following result:

```
**“o_file.txt”:**  
./i_dir/file_01.sh:1:GOOD_word  
./i_dir/file_01.sh:3:miao GOOD_word bau  
./i_dir/file_01.sh:5:GOOD_word foo  
./i_dir/file_02.sh:1:GOOD_word yes  
./i_dir/file_02.sh:3:GOOD_word bla
```

This is what I try so far, but does not work.

```
find ./dir -type f -exec grep -E -i -H "GOOD_word" {} \; | 
  grep -v “BAD_word” {} \; >> o_file.txt;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close - you just need to add `-n` for the line numbers and remove the second `{}` so that the `grep -v` operates on the output of the first grep, rather than on the found files:

```
$ find ./i_dir -type f -exec grep -E -i -H -n "GOOD_word" {} \; | grep -v "BAD_word"
./i_dir/file_01.sh:1:GOOD_word
./i_dir/file_01.sh:3:miao GOOD_word bau
./i_dir/file_01.sh:5:GOOD_word foo
./i_dir/file_02.sh:1:GOOD_word yes
./i_dir/file_02.sh:3:GOOD_word bla
```

I'm assuming that you need `-E` because your "real" `GOOD_word` is an extended regular expression - if that's not the case, you may omit it (and possibly also the `-i` flag).

Alternatively, you could do something like this, using bash globstar for the directory descent and awk for the logic:

```
shopt -s globstar
awk '/GOOD_word/ && !/BAD_word/{print FILENAME,FNR,$0}' OFS=: ./i_dir/**/*
```

See also

- [grep with logic operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/grep-with-logic-operators)

Answer (score 4):

You do not need `find`! ... `grep` has an option for that:

> **-r, --recursive**
> Read  all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links only if
> they are on the command line.  Note that if no file operand is given, grep searches
> the working directory.  This is equivalent to the -d recurse option.

or

> **-R, --dereference-recursive**
> Read  all  files  under  each  directory,  recursively.  Follow all symbolic links,
> unlike -r.

More options are in [man grep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/grep.1.html)

---

You can run the following from within the directory containing the three files.

To exclude only the word `BAD_word`:

```
sed 's/BAD_word//' <(grep -rwn "GOOD_word" .)
```

or to exclude the whole lines containing the word `BAD_word`:

```
grep -wv "BAD_word" <(grep -rwn "GOOD_word" .)
```